# Game time and pausing

Tags: timer, pausing

I am writing a simple game where some things happen after some amount of time. I used simple time analog of the framework I use to schedule these events, however, I have found that I will not be able to pause the game because the time is continuously increasing and nothing can stop it. So I decided to have my own time which is updated each `update()` function call to a delta time (example in Lua):

```
current_time = 0.0

function update(dt)
    current_time = current_time + dt
end
```

So I am able to pause the game now by simply not incrementing the game time and not doing anything at all (simply `return` from the `update` function). The question is do I do this correctly? Does every game engine do this this way? I just could not think of any other method for implementing game time with pausability.

P.S. `update` function is called in the game loop on each iteration. The fps is locked to a constant.

Comment: I think you should really just ask yourself: "is this working for me?", if yes then this is a good approach, if no maybe ask a question about how to implement the timer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to pause the game by not updating your game instead of updating it but with 0 delta time?

Comment: @Charanor I do exactly the same as you have just said.

Comment: How long do you expect your game to be played at a stretch? (Including, if it's on console, suspending/resuming across multiple sessions) The reason I ask is that adding a small float to a larger float can lose precision. If your deltaTime is a matter of milliseconds, then after 4 hours of play you'll start missing decimals here and there, and after 9 hours you'll be skipping milliseconds. If this is a round or level timer that's always reset after a few minutes or hours of play though, that might not be such a concern.

Comment: @DMGregory nice point. It may be so long, yes. I have also meant in the question that I am interested in all scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite way to pause a game is this:

```
void Update() {

    if (paused) {
        // handle paused state
        // maybe an animation is showing while game is paused
        // maybe something is moving around
        // actual game time is paused, but the app is still running
        return;
    }

    // Handle update
}
```

This way, if the game is paused, inside update, it will handle the paused interface and then return from `Update()` so it doesn't update the game itself. This depends on what engine/programming language you are using. I've used this when I made a custom game engine, and it was working amazingly well.

Comment: This very-very depends on what game world timer do you have - a time since the game start (usually SDL_Timer and so on) or your own timer which you increment in the update. If your game timers bound to the game start time so it is increased even if it paused and so the game is actually live this time and your "pause" is nothing. That's the problem.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy I'm not sure what you mean, I don't like implementing a "world timer" myself, this method assumes that you have control over what you are making, and everything is moving forward because of the `Update` method. If you are using an engine like unity, maybe this is not the best way to handle this.

Comment: This method will work if you are not incrementing your time during pause, i.e. not using a "time since the start of the game" in your various time checks. Meaning, under `// Handle update`, you would need to increment your time and then use that time throughout your various time checks (as opposed to simply using "time since the start of the game").